# setting a class to a menu depending of the url link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my scenario, my sub pages are not recognizing the parent, probably cause I set the structure bad, however going to back to fix that is not an option for now, problem the menu parent is getting the parent class in the wrong places....

So what I need to achieve...

if I have this url structure: domain.com/products/....  assign "current" class to menu X...

If I have this other: domain.com/sales/..... assign "current" class to Y....

I know I can do it via javascript, however I lack of knowledge of it, I'm just looking for a solid starting point.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the url and do your class assignment like this:

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('products') > 0){
  $("#somediv").addClass("current");
}
```

Without providing some sample of you're structure I can't really put together a more meaningful sample but you can see maybe how this would work out.